# How to simplify this on excel vba? is it possible?

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to simplify this expression on excel-vba. Is that possible?

```
[A1] = "=B1"
[A2] = "=B2"
[A3] = "=B3"
[A4] = "=B4"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use RC notation

```
Range("A1:A4").Formula = "=RC[1]"
```

or

```
[A1:A4] = "=RC[1]"
```

Answer (score 0):

And without RC notation:

```
Sub NoRC()
    Range("A1:A4").Formula = "=B1"
End Sub
```

also works.

*(this is because the **B1** will adjust going down the column)*

Comment: Right, but a little bit misleading IMHO